# Keep One Column but Using Other Columns in Pandas Groupby and Agg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a goal of grouping a dataset by certain column (identifier) and then perform some customized operations (first sort by date, and then concatenate the status).

Here is what I have done so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
text = """date  identifier  status
1/1/18  A   Pending
1/1/18  B   Pending
1/1/18  C   Pending
1/2/18  A   Approve
1/2/18  B   Pending
1/2/18  C   Pending
1/3/18  B   Approve
1/3/18  C   Pending"""
text = StringIO(text)
df = pd.read_csv(text, sep="\t") 

# group by identifier 
# within the group, sort by date
# then concatenate by status

def myfunc(df):
    df.sort_values(by="date", ascending=True)
    res = [s[0] for s in df['status']]
    return ''.join(res)

df.groupby(['identifier']).agg(lambda x: myfunc(x))

id  date  status        
A   PA  PA
B   PPA PPA
C   PPP PPP
```

It seems like the `agg` will apply the `lambda` function to each column, and when applied to each column, the whole group will be visible, which lead to `status` and `date` are present in the final outcome and share the same output. **I can drop the date column afterwards but does not seem ideal**.

I tried to specify the status column and then you will lose visibility to other columns that you want to include (for sorting).

```
def myfunc1(x):
print(x)

df.groupby(['identifier']).agg({'status': lambda x: myfunc1(x)}) 
0    Pending
3    Approve
Name: status, dtype: object
1    Pending
4    Pending
6    Approve
Name: status, dtype: object
2    Pending
5    Pending
7    Pending
Name: status, dtype: object
```

In summary, how shall I use the agg function properly to get the final outcome

```
id   status        
A    PA
B    PPA
C    PPP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can slice first and then just `agg`

```
df['letter'] = df.status.str[0]
df.groupby('identifier').letter.agg(''.join)

identifier
A     PA
B    PPA
C    PPP
```

---

But if you really want to use your `myfunc`, you can correct that by doing

1. Assigning back the `sort_values` (or removing it entirely): The way it is now, you are sorting but not using the return value of `sort_values`. Thus, nothing is actually being done. (I believe you should `sort_values` before going `groupby` and `agg`, and not inside `agg func`.
2. Specify you want to `agg` the`status` col, and not *all* cols. You can do that in two ways, as shown below

Code would go like:

```
def myfunc(ser):
    res = [s[0] for s in ser]
    return ''.join(res)

df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
df.groupby(['identifier']).agg({'status': lambda x: myfunc(x)})
```

or

```
df.groupby(['identifier']).status.agg(lambda x: myfunc(x))

#same as 
df.groupby(['identifier']).status.agg(myfunc)
```

Comment: After grouping, how to sort by date but concatenate the status? The second half of your code is sorting on status instead of dates.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. true. Just do `df.sort_values(by='date')` before everything

Comment: That works, I guess if I really want to specify which columns to use during aggregation and also being picky about the outputted column(s), I might have to loop through the grouped object instead of using agg directly.